# Rewriting URL address on a site

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, rules

in my website I have links like this - http://example.com/index.php?page=about and I want to make them look like this - http://example.com/about

Is it possible and if it is what should I do to get this result?

Comment: it's reward of our research. is it so difficult to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `mod_rewrite` and here is the [first](http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite) and [second](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php) guide.

In your case just create `.htaccess` file in root folder and write following code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```